# Create email from PowerShell using Task Scheduler (Runtime Error 429)

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, automation, runtime-error

I created several scripts to send emails after performing certain analysis. This has worked previously. Now a few of the scripts fail and give the following error message:

> run-time error '429':
> ActiveX component can't create object

It then refers to the Outlook Object line of code as the error.

The script runs when I exit MS Outlook and bugs out if Outlook is running. I use a Task Scheduler to run this and Outlook is usually going to be running.

```vb
Private Sub Send_Ratings_Email()

    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim StrBody As String
    StrBody = "Please find  Maturities for the Current Week Below: "

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If OutApp Is Nothing Then Set OutApp = GetObject("Outlook.Application")

    On Error GoTo cleanup
 
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    On Error Resume Next
            
    Call AddAzureLabel(OutMail, "Restricted - Internal")
    With OutMail
        .To = " example.com"
        .Subject = "Weekly Maturities - W/C " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy")
        .HTMLBody = StrBody & RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Display  'Or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Powershell Script works when manually run.

Comment: Has your environment recently changed? This could be a security setting in Outlook that does not allow programmatic access. You may need to toggle that in the File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Programmatic Access.

Comment: Hi David - thanks for your help. This section seems to be okay. I cannot understand why the Excel macro when called from a Powershell script in Task Scheduler doesnt work

Comment: Hmmmm. There's a LOT of info about possible error source via Microsoft, here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/828550/you-receive-run-time-error-429-when-you-automate-office-applications

Comment: I'd be curious to know if you get the same powershell/task scheduler error while using `GetObject` instead of `CreateObject`.

Comment: I've taken out the code If         OutApp Is Nothing Then Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")   and now all that happens is the task scheduler performs the analysis and closes

Comment: That's not what I asked, though. That line of code seems like it would have pretty much no real effect, `OutApp` is always nothing until it's instantiated, and unless you're using global scoped variables (don't) it will not be instantiated until you call on `CreateObject` or `GetObject` to handle the possibly-already-running instance.

Comment: It might help for you to revise your question to show the code that you're currently using :)

Comment: Still issues. may this isnt possible. Hard to believe that even when I manually run the powershell script it works just Task Scheduler doesnt

Comment: It is possible, you're just doing something wrong or have something wrongly configured, and we haven't figured out what that/those are, yet :)

Comment: code amended to show what I am using - in order to reduce comments I'll just edit this one for replies. Really hope we can solve this

Comment: `Set OutApp = GetObject("Outlook.Application")` is wrong, you need to use either `GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")` or `CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`. That's why your program is just exiting in that case, you're getting an error on that assignment and it's following the `GoTo cleanup`.

Comment: Is Task Scheduler running PS from the same account? If not, could be a permissions issue or other configuration. Have you tried repairing the installs of both Outlook and Excel? Just in case.

Comment: Yeah - the TS is running the PS from the same account. repairs are okay. The error coming up is  ActiveX component cant create object. But Outlook is already open. The TS works when outlook is not open

Comment: see my "answer" below, I'm curious what happens if we encapsulate the Outlook instantiation. Can you run that `foo` procedure from PS and see what happens?

Comment: Sure - just tried no luck, it opens and dont believe it even runs the macro. manually on powershell it works however.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an instance of outlook if its running it won't work, instead check if it's already running and get the running app or create one if its not:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If OutApp Is Nothing Then Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

Comment: I'd place OEG0 after getting obj in case creating obj also fails.

Comment: *You are creating an instance of outlook if its running it won't work*  This is not actually true. You can `CreateObject` even if Outlook is already running. In this case, `CreateObject` returns the already-running instance.

Comment: Replace your `Set OutApp...` line with the block on my answer, that should fix it.

Comment: thanks...getting an error saying it cannot create component. Highlighting 'Set OutApp = Create'.... within the IF Statement.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you have the `Microsoft Outlook XX.X Object Library` checked on your References? Being XX.X the version of your outlook.

Comment: Yes - got the object ref library for outlook checked.  Outlook16.0  - Edit: the script seems to work when i manually run the macro but not with the task scheduler - which is crazy as it has worked in the past

Comment: That is weird... really no logic on your error. For starters, if Outlook is already open it should avoid the second Set, and If it isn't... You had no problem with that.

Comment: damn it - I am guessing nothing else I could do? I just cannot understand why it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Untick 'Run with highest privileges' in your Task Scheduler task

Answer (score 0):

Adding this as an answer for now, but really just trying to debug in a way that won't fit in comments. Similar to the other answer, but the idea is to use this to create a test case and let's see if we can get it to work in your Task Scheduler>Powershell case.

Have your PS run the `foo` or `foo2` procedure here, and I've encapsulated the Outlook instantiation as a standalone function to try and keep things clean and isolate the error.

```
Option Explicit

Sub foo()
Dim olApp As Object
Set olApp = GetApplication("Outlook.Application")

End Sub

Sub foo2()
Dim olApp As Object
Set olApp = GetApplication2("Outlook.Application")
End Sub

Function GetApplication2(className As String) As Object
' function to encapsulate the instantiation of an application object
Dim theApp As Object
On Error Resume Next
Set theApp = CreateObject(className)
If theApp Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Unable to get a handle on " & className
Else
    MsgBox "Successfully got a handle on " & className & ", returning to caller"
End If
Set GetApplication2 = theApp
End Function


Function GetApplication(className As String) As Object
' function to encapsulate the instantiation of an application object
Dim theApp As Object
On Error Resume Next
Set theApp = GetObject(, className)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Unable to Get" & className & ", attempting to CreateObject"
    Set theApp = CreateObject(className)
End If

If theApp Is Nothing Then
    Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, "Unable to Get or Create the " & className & "!"
    Set GetApplication = Nothing
End If

MsgBox "Successfully got a handle on Outlook Application, returning to caller"

Set GetApplication = theApp

End Function
```

Which I'm running from PS like:

```
$excel = new-object -comobject excel.application
$file = "C:\debug\ps-excel.xlsm"
$wb = $excel.workbooks.open($file)
$excel.Run("Module1.foo")
```

And:

```
$excel.Run("Module1.foo2")
```

In the `foo` procedure, `GetObject` raises an error but it's not a 429 error, and control passes to `CreateObject` which successfully instantiates the application. So, **unfortunately I'm not able to reproduce the error** under any combination of `foo`/`foo2` and whether Outlooks is already open does not seem to matter, either.

## Here's a somewhat hack-y potential solution

So, this is a bit hack-y because I don't think it solves the root cause (and because I can't replicate your error, it might not actually solve anything) but it's worth a shot, as you note:

> Important to note that the script runs when I exit MS Outlook and bugs out if Outlook is already running

My idea is to just modify your PS to check for running instance of Outlook and close it via `stop-process` Cmdlet.

```
try {
    stop-process -Name "outlook" -ErrorAction Stop
    Write-Host "Stopped the running instance of Outlook Application"
    } catch { 
    Write-Host "outlook was not already running"
    } 
    
$excel = new-object -comobject excel.application
$file = "C:\debug\ps-excel.xlsm"
$wb = $excel.workbooks.open($file)
$excel.run("Module1.foo")
```

Comment: I ran this via - TS/PS and it opens and no pop up appeared either way. However, when I manually run from Powershell the instance works

Comment: @dsound I revised my test functions to try and give some more detail when run from PS.

Comment: @dsound would you try using the `stop-process` cmdlet to kill Outlook if it's already running, via PowerShell? Kind of a hack, but it might work.

Comment: ahh no use - the error is still coming up with the hack. It says that outlook was not already running and then proceeds with the error  :(

Comment: that's wack, nothing about this makes sense -- so now, even if Outlook is NOT running (PS kills the process) it still errors? I wish I could reproduce your error, but I can't. It works for me exactly the way that I think it should. There has got to be some sort of configuration, registry, or permissions issue on your end, but I don't know how to help isolate that root cause :(

Comment: Yeah it sucks - I downloaded Advanced Task Scheduler - ran the powershell script there and no issues at all. The only issue is that Adv. Task Scheduler isn't free its only a trial.

Comment: I even went a step further and tried to run mine via Task Scheduler (i had been just running PS from command prompt). Still can't get the error, mine successfully closes the running instance of Outlook (if it's open) and in either case then does what it needs to do in Excel. I would double- and triple-check the options in Task Scheduler. Otherwise, sorry I can't be of more help!